# Proof of Kahn-Kalai Conjecture (Park, Pham)

Tags: probability, graph-theory

I have a question about one inequality in the paper of Pham and Park where they proof the Kahn Kalai Conjecture. So there they use the following theorem:
For $l \geq 2$ there exists a universal $L > 0$ such that for every nonempty l-bounded hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$ on X that is not p-small, a uniform random (Lp log l)|X|-element subset of X belongs to $\langle \mathcal{H} \rangle = \bigcup_{S \in \mathcal{H}} \{T: T \supseteq S \}$ with probability $1-o_{l \to \infty}(1)$.
Then in the last line of there computation they have the following inequalities
$$P(X_{p'} \in \langle \mathcal{H} \rangle ) \geq P(X_m \in \langle \mathcal{H} \rangle) P(|X_{p'}| \geq m) \geq (3/4) P(|X_{p'}| \geq m) \overset{?}{>} 1/2$$
In the paper they state that the last inequality follows from a "standard concentration bound" but I don't know what they mean by that. I just heard once that someone called the Chebyshev inequality a concentration inequality but I don't see if this is meant here.
You can find the given inequality in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.17207.pdf at page 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a "concentration bound" or "concentration inequality" is any inequality showing that the probability mass of a random variable is concentrated: that the random variable is very likely to be in some interval much smaller than its overall range. Usually, this happens because the small interval is a small interval around the mean, and the random variable is very likely to be close to the mean.

Here, we are looking at $|X_{p'}|$: the size of a random subset of $X$ sampled so that every element is in the subset with probability $p' = 2Lq \log \ell$. This is a binomial random variable with $|X|$ trials and probability $p'$ of success. We want the probability that $|X_{p'}| \ge m$, where $m = (Lq \log \ell)|X|$, which we can write as $\frac12 p' |X|$, and we want this probability to be large: to have the quoted inequality $$\frac34 P(|X_{p'}| \ge m) > \frac12$$ we must have $P(|X_{p'}| \ge m) > \frac23$. Equivalently, $P(|X_{p'}| < m) < \frac13$.

(Why does this call for a concentration inequality? Because we expect $|X_{p'}|$ to be tightly concentrated around $p'|X|$, so that it is very rarely below $\frac12p'|X|$.)

Chebyshev's inequality is indeed a concentration inequality, so let's see if it will be enough here. The random variable $|X_{p'}|$ has expected value $p'|X|$ and variance $p'(1-p')|X|$, so if $|X_{p'}| < m$, that means that it is more than $$\frac{p'|X|-m}{\sqrt{p'(1-p')|X|}} = \frac{\frac12 p'|X|}{\sqrt{p'(1-p')|X|}} = \sqrt{\frac{p'|X|}{4(1-p')}}$$
standard deviations below the mean, so Chebyshev's inequality says that $$P(|X_{p'}| < m) < \frac{4(1-p')}{p'|X|} = \frac{2(1-p')}{m} < \frac2m.$$
In order to get this below $\frac13$, it's enough to have $m \ge 6$, hence the remark in the paper that $m$ "is somewhat large". So Chebyshev's inequality does work!

The other things that a "standard concentration bound" could be are Chernoff-type inequalities, named after the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)) (though using something like [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) would be equally reasonable). If we try them, we find that they also work.

In general, for bounding binomial and binomial-like random variables this far below the mean, all these inequalities are interchangeable, which is possibly a reason the paper authors didn't specify. Chebyshev's inequality will tell us that the probability of being more than $k$ standard deviations below the mean is bounded by $\frac1{k^2}$; Chernoff-type inequalities will give an answer that decays more like $e^{-k^2}$, with various constants in the exponent depending on the situation. Here, because $k$ is at least $\sqrt{m/2}$, *any* of these will work provided that $m$ is at least some small constant.